# Capture the area within a square box using camera in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I want to show a square box on my camera screen and I want to capture the area within that square box how I can achieve that?
It will not scan any bar code or QR code it will simply capture the area within a square box and skip all the rest.

**this is the image of the view**

[image]

Comment: Have you archived this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve directly. Follow the step as  :

1. Snap : this.camera.takePictureAsync({ fixOrientation: true, mirrorImage: true })
2. Crop with ImageEditor by setting cropData as

   const { uri, width, height } = capturedImg;

   {
   offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
   size: { imagewidth, height }, displaySize: { width: cameraSize.width, height: cameraSize.height }
   }
3. Now crop your camera size photo with box origin and size